# How to show user file size before uploading?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, coldfusion, upload

I have unsuccessfully been trying to get the file size of an upload before the user actually uploads it. I know this is a common query which I thought was impossible because there (AFAIK) you can't determine the file size until its been uploaded first.

However I came across some screenshots for Flickr's upload screen and they seem to show the file size before uploading. How is this being done? I am using ColdFusion and JQuery as my server and client technologies - if a potential suggestion could be compatible with these languages that would be much appreciated.

[image: Flickr Image Upload Screen]

Comment: Thank you for the link to the other solved question. But does that mean that non-HTML5 browsers cannot show the file size? It may ruin the UI in that case and tell the user they're uploading a file of `null` size. This would confuse them into thinking they're uploading nothing!

Comment: numerous scripts around that also have feature detection in them to account for older browsers